# jquery, чем заменить запись

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как заменить вот такую часть кода - конкретные id - делать disabled?

```
$("#3 *").prop('disabled',true);
$("#4 *").prop('disabled',true);
$("#5 *").prop('disabled',true);
$("#6 *").prop('disabled',true);
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

В jQuery, как и в CSS, можно перечислять селекторы через запятую:

```
$('#1 *, #2 *, #3 *').prop('disabled',true);
```

Еще можно использовать селектор по аттрибуту, если у вас айдишники более конкретные:

```
$('[id^="field"]>*').prop('disabled',true);
// Установит disabled для всех непосредственных (первого уровня) потомков
// всех элементов, чей id начинается с "field".
```